# Copy-Item not redirecting error to log file

Tags: powershell

I have the following line in Powershell 4.0, which takes a log file and causes an error (or possibly an exception?):

`copy-item C:\Source\PSLog.txt C:\Source\Test2\ *>> C:\Source\Log.txt`

It is supposed to generate an error, as `\Test2\` doesn't exist. I'm doing this to try to test how I can catch problems with copy-items in a larger script.

However, when I run this it directs the copy-item error into the console rather than redirecting it to Log.txt as I would expect. I've also tried to use | out-file, but that doesn't pull anything at all into the file.

Any idea why I can't catch the exception/error?

Comment: What is your powershell version? It needs to be at least 3.0 for that to work.

Comment: Have you considered using a Try/Catch block instead or trying to redirect stderr to a text file?

Comment: I have considered using a Try/Catch block there, but I'd still need to direct the exceptions somewhere other than the console so I can look at it later, as this is part of a larger automation that runs during off-hours.

Comment: Additionally, there would be a switch/argument error if I were running in 2.0, since *>> doesn't exist in 2.0.

Comment: By the way, I decided to go with a Try > Catch and using $Error to push the content into a log, ultimately. More reliable, readable, and better overall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in the comments, the `*>>` only works in PowerShell 3.0 and newer. You can use cmd-style handle redirection (`>&`) instead, works in version 2.0 as well:

```
if($PSVersionTable.PSVersion.Major -lt 3) {
    copy-item C:\Source\PSLog.txt C:\Source\Test2\ >> C:\Source\Log.txt 2>&1
} else {
    copy-item C:\Source\PSLog.txt C:\Source\Test2\ *>> C:\Source\Log.txt
}
```

But you're probably better off just inspecting the contents of the `$Error` automatic variable instead. `$Error[0]` will contain the latest error

Comment: The example doesn't redirect the error into Log.txt in PS 4.0 (I updated the question to include that), but still displays the error in the console. $Error does include what I'm looking for, so I can work with that.

Comment: @SeanLong My bad, in that case you'll need to check the version, example updated, but yeah, handling exceptions and collecting details from `$Error` is definitely a more viable option

Comment: Makes sense. That would totally work, regardless of where you're running now. Ultimately, I went with a Try > Catch block and pushing $Error[0] into the log if it catches anything, instead of just dumping everything into the log. Thanks!